# How to correctly configure resilience 4J fall back client with annotations?

Tags: spring-boot, resilience4j

As the title suggests, below is a class that hooks to a `Euereka` registry as per YAML configs, and looks for a nonexistent client `fallback-test` URL.

```
@FeignClient(name = "fallback-test", configuration = TestFallbackClientLoggingConfiguration.class)
public interface TestFallbackClient {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, path = "/fall-back-not-found-data")
    @CircuitBreaker(name = "fall-back-not-found", fallbackMethod = "getFallbackBrokenCircuit")
    String getFallbackData(@RequestParam(value = "uid") String uid);

    default String getFallbackBrokenCircuit(String uid, Throwable cause) {
        if (cause instanceof FeignException) {
            return "COULD NOT GET FALL BACK DATA";
        } else {
            return cause.toString();
        }
    }
}

@Configuration
class TestFallbackClientLoggingConfiguration {

    @Bean
    Logger.Level feignTestFallbackClientLoggerLevel() {
        return Logger.Level.BASIC;
    }
}
```

This is the unit test, which to my understanding should work, or rather shows my intention.

```
@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
class TestFallbackClientTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestFallbackClient testFallbackClient;

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Test fall back client implementation")
    public void test_fall_back_client_gives_fallback_text() {
        String data = testFallbackClient.getFallbackData("some_invalid_data");
        assertEquals("COULD NOT GET FALL BACK DATA", data);
    }
}
```

Since the URL does not exist, I expect `Eureka` to give me back a `503` or such error, and thus provide me back with the fallback default text `COULD NOT GET FALL BACK DATA`

However, this is the error I am getting on the application startup.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

  at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132)
  at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:124)
  at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190)
  at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132)
  at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:244)
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:138)
  at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:350)
  at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:355)
  at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$7(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:350)
  at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
  at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
  at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
  at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
  at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
  at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:312)
  at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
  at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
  at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:658)
  at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:349)
  at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:270)
  at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
  at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:269)
  at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$2(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:259)
  at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:362)
  at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$3(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:258)
  at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31)
  at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:101)
  at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
  at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:100)
  at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
  at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$1(NodeTestTask.java:111)
  at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
  at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:111)
  at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:79)
  at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
  at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
  at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
  at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
  at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
  at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
  at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
  at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
  at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
  at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
  at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
  at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
  at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
  at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
  at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
  at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
  at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
  at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
  at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
  at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
  at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
  at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
  at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
  at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
  at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
  at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
  at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
  at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
  at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
  at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
  at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
  at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
  at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:221)
  at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on io.github.resilience4j.retry.autoconfigure.AbstractRetryConfigurationOnMissingBean.retryRegistry
  at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60)
  at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108)
  at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:193)
  at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:153)
  at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:129)
  at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:343)
  at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247)
  at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311)
  at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112)
  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746)
  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564)
  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:769)
  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761)
  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426)
  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326)
  at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:123)
  at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
  at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
  ... 67 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [io.github.resilience4j.retry.autoconfigure.AbstractRetryConfigurationOnMissingBean] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@3d4eac69]
  at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:481)
  at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:358)
  at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:371)
  at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:414)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.lambda$getTypeForFactoryMethod$2(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:747)
  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1708)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:746)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:685)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:656)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1670)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:570)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:542)
  at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:238)
  at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:231)
  at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:221)
  at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:169)
  at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:144)
  at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47)
  ... 84 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/github/resilience4j/core/ContextAwareScheduledThreadPoolExecutor
  at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
  at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3244)
  at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2387)
  at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:463)
  ... 101 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.github.resilience4j.core.ContextAwareScheduledThreadPoolExecutor
  at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
  at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
  at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
  ... 105 more
```

It is currently not clear to me how to use `resilience-4j` library. The reference page for open feign https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/feign has examples of feign decorators, but then how do I use them and hook them up to the feign class. When going through the code sample on that page, it seems to completely ignore the decorators.

To make the things work I just threw the kitchen sink, and as per the docs included this into YAML

```
resilience4j.circuitbreaker:
  configs:
    default:
      registerHealthIndicator: true
      slidingWindowSize: 10
      minimumNumberOfCalls: 5
      permittedNumberOfCallsInHalfOpenState: 3
      automaticTransitionFromOpenToHalfOpenEnabled: true
      waitDurationInOpenState: 5s
      failureRateThreshold: 50
      eventConsumerBufferSize: 10
      recordExceptions:
        - org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException
        - java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        - java.io.IOException
      ignoreExceptions:
        - io.github.robwin.exception.BusinessException

resilience4j.retry:
  configs:
    default:
      maxRetryAttempts: 3
      waitDuration: 100
      retryExceptions:
        - org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException
        - java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        - java.io.IOException
      ignoreExceptions:
        - io.github.robwin.exception.BusinessException
```

But even that didn't help. The library says, that you can pick and choose, so I am pretty sure for my use case of just one fallback client to give me null, how do I configure it with minimal configuration.

Do I really have to create all the separate configuration classes, like bulkheads, retrying, and circuit breaker? That seems to go contrary to the aims of the library.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: For anyone who is referring to this question, I was dumb and had the previous configurations for Hystrix and ribbon still active in my YAML file, which was cannibalizing the Resilience 4J implementation. Removing those entries, resolved my problem.